# solve null pointer exception at 'org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion.getTexture()'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, andengine

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion.getTexture()' on a null object reference

        at org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite.preDraw(Sprite.java:243)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1354)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1162)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1385)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1162)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1385)
        at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:260)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1162)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:627)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:617)
        at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
```

getting nullpointer exception. Does not get any idea to solve it.

Comment: no its not useful

Comment: show the code which is producing the exception

Comment: Some of object will be _null_. eg. `ITexture`

Comment: @Override
 protected void preDraw(final GLState pGLState, final Camera pCamera) {
  super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
    //////********** getting error here***********//////
        this.getTextureRegion().getTexture().bind(pGLState);
  try {

  }catch (Exception e){}

  this.mSpriteVertexBufferObject.bind(pGLState, this.mShaderProgram);
 }

Comment: Have you checked in Github library issues?

Answer (score 0):

Look in `org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite.java` on line 243. There is a reference to an `org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion` in there which is null... meaning it has not been initialised.

Without seeing the actual code, it is impossible to provide an explanation as to why the `ITextureRegion` is uninitialised.

For you to understand this better, I recommend reading [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: this.getTextureRegion().getTexture().bind(pGLState);    at this getting null pointer

Comment: Yes. So the value returned by `this.getTextureRegion()` is null. Determining the reason is impossible without having access to the code.